# Jquery check each paragraph for a date, check if the date is past/current and add class

Tags: jquery, datetime, addclass

I have such code:

```
<div class="content_inner">
    ...
    <p>2015 11 18 - Some dynamic text</p>
    <p>2015 11 19 - Some dynamic text</p>
    <p>2015 11 20 - Some dynamic text</p>
    <p>2015 11 21 - Some dynamic text</p>   
    <p>2015 11 22 - Some dynamic text</p>   
    <p>2015 11 23 - Some dynamic text</p>   
    <p>2015 11 24 - Some dynamic text</p>   
    ... 
</div>
```

- I'm getting all those paragraphs from WYSIWYG field.
- Each line will have the date (Y m D)

What i want:

Check each paragraph line for a date and:
1. if the date is today add class `<p class="today">`

2. If the date is < today add class `<p class="past">`

Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: from where these dates were come..??

Comment: It's a part of text, but it will be added to each line and always after <p>

Comment: @void all i have is in my question. Not sure how to make this function in jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/_vijaydev/osL8rr6L/) example to solve this.

**Please note:** that this solution assumes that the date values inside the `<p>` tag will be like that always.

Good luck, have fun!

Comment: Thanks @vijay ! It works just perfect! Thank you so much. Have a nice weekend ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
// Iterate every p inside content_inner
$(".content_inner p").each(function(){

    // Fetch Text of the current p
    var _text = $(this).text();

    // Fetch Date 2015 11 18 using split
    _text = _text.split(" - ")[0];

    // Seprate date components using split again
    _date = _text.split(" ");

    // Get current date
    var x = new Date();

    // Check if the date is current date (Note: Month starts from 0 in js)
    if(x.getFullYear() == +_date[0] && _x.getMonth()==(+x[1] + 1) && _x.getDate()==+_date[2])
    {
        // Add class today if it is todays date
        $(this).addClass("today");
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).addClass("past");
    }

});
```

Comment: I have added this code after my code, but i'm getting "Uncaught ReferenceError: _x is not defined"